# Do I have .NET dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

The following are all the headers I'm including when I pick and create an empty project and add a C++ file:

```
stdio.h
windows.h
tlhelp32.h
```

The program is stable when there is a .NET 4.0 installation on the system. I don't know where I use .NET in my program. There is just a resource file, but this too doesn't use .NET related stuff.

Also, I can't migrate into framework 3.5 without building a new project (it's 4.0 now), and it seems to switch to 4.0 after compiling, even though I checked for 2.0.

---

One Win32 C++ empty project (`/clr`) and one empty project with C Windows API.

Comment: Are you building with or without the `/clr` option?

Comment: "When i pick > create empty project " - is that a Win32 C++ project or a C++/CLR project?

Answer (score 2):

If you're compiling with /clr, then I believe that you do have a .NET dependency - that switch affects the type of binary produced by the compiler.  Regardless of whether you actually use .NET types or features, if you compile with /clr then you'll get a .NET assembly.